# Is it possible to return a View from a Controller method that is not the Index?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently getting started with MVC, but I can't seem to manipulate my view with my controller if I'm not using...

```
public ActionResult Index() { 
    return View();
}
```

When I use a function that is not Index() to attempt to update, it seems as if the page is not changing at all.  In fact, it seems like the page steps into all of the expected controller and partial view calls, but then just loads the default page anyway.  I think I'm doing something wrong in how I'm communicating with my view.

Here is my current process:

Created the view with controls.  I want my user to enter search data, click the search button, and begin my query to retrieve results.  The results will be displayed in a web grid once they are retrieved.

```
    <div class="searchOneWrp">
        <fieldset>
            <legend><strong>Patient One Search</strong></legend>
            First Name: <input type="text" id="fnamePone" />
            Last Name: <input type="text" id="lnamePone" />
            D.O.B.: <input type="text" id="dobPone" />
            <button class="patient_look_up_button" id="btnPOneSearch" name="btnPOneSearch" type="submit" onclick="patientOneSearch()"
                    title="Search">
                Search
            </button>
        </fieldset>
        @if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("PatientOneSearch");
        }
    </div>
```

My model:

```
namespace myNameSpace.Repository.Model
{
    public class PatientMerge
    {
        public int pat_id { get; set; }
        public string pag_status_cn { get; set; }
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public string lname { get; set; }
        public string birth_date { get; set; }
        public string AgeYears { get; set; }
        public string gender_cd { get; set; }
        public string phone_no { get; set; }
        public string addr1 { get; set; }
        public string addr2 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state_cd { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My AJAX gets to my Controller for my query:

```
        public PartialViewResult GetPatientOneSearch(string fname, string lname, string dob)
        {
            try
            {
                var target = new PatientRepository();
                var result = target.GetPatient(fname, lname, dob, "", "", "");
                List<myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge> patientList = new List<myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge>();

                for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
                {
                    myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge patient = new myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge();
                    patient.pat_id = result[i].PatientId;
                    patient.fname = result[i].FirstName;
                    patient.lname = result[i].LastName;
                    patient.birth_date = result[i].DateOfBirth.ToString();

                    patientList.Add(patient);
                }
                return PartialView("PatientOneSearch", patientList);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Log.Error(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + ex.InnerException);
                //return Json(new { error = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                return PartialView("PatientOneSearch", null);
            }
        }
```

Which then goes to my Partial View...

```
@model IEnumerable<myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge>

<div id="grdPatientOneSearch">
    @if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
    {
        var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
        grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid",
        headerStyle: "header",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        selectedRowStyle: "select",
        columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("pat_id", "Id"),
        grid.Column("fname", "First Name"),
        grid.Column("lname", "Last Name"),
        grid.Column("birth_date", "dob")
        )
        );
    }
    else
    {
        <label>No records found.</label>
    }
```

Aaaaaand nothing displays on in my browser.  In fact, with all the testing I've done, I swear it just returns the default view.  It does not actually hit my return View(); above, but from all the testing I've attempted to do in the last 2 days, I swear that has to be what is happening.

Am I doing something wrong in how I'm updating my view?

Comment: What view are you trying to return? And are you sure you want a view returned? or redirect to another controller action?

Comment: @code I'm trying to return the partial: return PartialView("PatientOneSearch", patientList);

Comment: @user2864740 It's relevant information, but requires digestion.  The requests are all shown in the code I've posted above.  Only thing I didn't show was my AJAX.  Figured it was obvious I'd be calling a controller with that part (I'm calling 'PatientOneSearch', the controller shown).  The intro tutorials I've found do not answer my question.  Please link one if you find it.  Can't help but feel you're being rude to me.

Comment: Are you getting a blank screen, or is part of the view (like your header) rendering?

Comment: @TiesonT. I'm getting the return of my default Index, which is basically any HTML I initially set in my parent view.  Equal to a blank screen in functionality.

Comment: Are you trying to get your partial view inside your html of your index view?

Comment: @code Yes.  Partial contains search results I fill with my Model object.  The WebGrid is expecting the Model and I would expect this code to function as expected.  I can see all of the events getting hit in the debugger, but nothing changes in the browser.

Comment: @Smak you're not passing your partial view a model so it should render whatever html is in the partial view withouat a model

Comment: @code Does it not pass in my controller?

Comment: Is your partial view model same as parent view model? if they are different no it doesn't

Comment: Yes they are both of type @model IEnumerable<myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge>

Comment: What does your JS look like?

Comment: @code GetAjax('PatientMerge/GetPatientOneSearch', 'json', { 'fname': fname, 'lname': lname, 'dob': dob }, function (data) { } );

Comment: Is the button click function **patientOneSearch()** a javascript ffunction?

Comment: GetAjax is a helper functional.  Formats to /PatientMerge/GetPatientOneSearch in the URL

Comment: I added an answer because I didnt want to rewrite all that but see if it helps

Comment: Your parial view method returns html so using JQuery set your div html to that

Comment: @code Ah I I get what you're saying now.  I'll give it a shot.  I'm pretty sure I can figure something out with that thinking.

Comment: Oh, great. Another SO opinionated moderator deleted one of my comments. Shame on you.

Comment: @user2864740 Well, your original comment as not exactly constructive, so I can't say I'm surprised it was removed.

Comment: @TiesonT. Not constructive to 1) indicate that the OP should look at what was *really* happening and 2) the title question (and "assumption") can be trivially answered and eliminated from consideration? The rest of the irrelevant (and I do stick with that) is not related to the specific question, is not an SSCCE, and is a "Why isn't this code working?" (Just remembered to put in the close vote..)

Comment: @user2864740 While the length of the comments on this question are an obvious sign of a question not well asked, and (possibly) that the OP doesn't really know this domain all that well, the tone of your comments comes off as somewhat aggressive (which for some translates to "rude"), and could be summed up as JFGI. *I* didn't flag your comment. I didn't think it was helpful, but I could see why someone would remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to just make a second answer for this one why not just set your html to

```
<div class="searchOneWrp">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><strong>Patient One Search</strong></legend>
        First Name: <input type="text" id="fnamePone" />
        Last Name: <input type="text" id="lnamePone" />
        D.O.B.: <input type="text" id="dobPone" />
        <button class="patient_look_up_button" id="btnPOneSearch" name="btnPOneSearch" type="submit" onclick="patientOneSearch()"
                title="Search">
            Search
        </button>
    </fieldset>
    @if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
    {
        <div id="patientSearchPartial">

        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Then in your JS code

```
GetAjax('PatientMerge/GetPatientOneSearch', 'json', { 'fname': fname, 'lname': lname, 'dob': dob }, function (data) { 
    $('#patientSearchPartial').html(data);  
} )
```

Because your partial view Action Result returns html why not use jquery to fill that div with html returned
Now it will hit your partial view and refill the html with data from controller

Comment: Well, I think this is the right idea, but it needs to use a web grid (really trying to avoid table rows).  The data I'm returning is a List of my model objects that would (in ASPX world) be able to bind to a gridview.

Does your solution do something similar?  I have not tried it.

Comment: Table ROws? This has nothing to do with tables, this just pulls html from the partial view action method

Comment: Whatever html is in your partial view **PatientOneSearch** is being returned with the model passed from the controller

Comment: I understand.  I'm pretty sure I can make something happen with this.  Thanks for sticking with me.

Comment: Depending on what GetAjax is doing internally, you might be able to replace that with [jquery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: As @Tieson T. said **load** is possible, JQuery is very strong

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest getting more knowledge with mvc but you can do anything from your controller. Using your controller code

```
public ActionResult Index() { 
    return View();
}
```

This is just the action that your controller runs anytime you look for the **Index** view. If you wanted to hit say **blah** view you could write it as:

```
public ActionResult Blah() { 
    return View();
}
```

If you wanted your **Index** action to take you to the view it can do that as well

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    //Do some code and grab MyModel 
    return View("Blah", MyModel);
}
```

Here it's gonna hit the **Blah** view whenever the **Index** action is called because instead of just telling it to return the **View()**(Which just returns the view that has the same name as the Action Result) you're telling it to return a different view, and model.

You could also have something like

```
public ActionResult Index() { 
    return RedirectToAction("Blah")
}
```

Which will redirect to **Blah** Action Result

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with the theory of code's approach.  Really, I was able to better form my question with this discussion and find the resources I needed to get a grip on how partial views are rendered.

```
$.post(url, { 'fname': fname, 'lname': lname, 'dob': dob, patientNumber: 1 })
        .done(function (response) {
            $("#grdPatientTwoSearch").html(response);
        });
```

Partial views will call your controller (MUST CALL FROM SCRIPT) and the controller will return HTML to your script.  You then need to bind the response to the web page, similar to how I have done above.

I used this resource to help myself understand:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/revisiting-partial-view-rendering-in-asp.net-mvc/